# Regular expression that matches quotes that are not escaped in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex in JAVA that would match a string like: 'test " abcd \" ef" test'
Let's say that I would want to know if between the quotes I have the characters abcdef in this order and any other character between them (but since I'm interested only in the substring between the quotes, the character between them can't be a quote, except the case in which the quote is escaped)
Is it possible to do this?

I managed to create this regex

```
("[^\"]*\"[^\"]*a[^\"]*b[^\"]*c[^\"]*d[^\"]*e[^\"]*f[^\"]*\"[^\"]*")
```

that works for any case except the ones with escaped quotes embedded in the string.

Comment: Can you clarify with more examples.

Comment: I guess the simplest way to put it would be: I need something like [^\"]* (that matches anything but quotes), but that also matches escaped quotes

Comment: So in your string `test " abcd \" ef" test` you want output as: `abcd \" ef` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there... add the case for the quoted quote, which can be matched with

```
\\\"
```

so each of your `[^\"]*` cases (except the first and last, I guess) should become

```
([^\"]|\\\")*
```

... but you also need to take care of backslashes  (because, for example, in

```
"foo\\"
```

the final quote is a "real" (non-escaped) quote, even though there's a backslash before it.) So in fact you need the `[^\"]*` cases to become:

```
([^\"\\]|\\.)*
```

or in other words: match anything that's not `\` or `"`, or is `\` followed by a character that's ignored.

NB This will mean that, for example, in the string `"xxx\abcdef"` the `"\a"` will not be matched as an `"a"`, but that's probably what you want (since `"\a"` typically denotes the ASCII "BEL" control character).